# How to return array [0] item. but it always return 'Nothing to do.'

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function nextAction(arr) {
  if (nextAction = []) {
    return 'Nothing to do.';
  } else {
    return [0];
  }
}
console.log(nextAction(['tea', 'coffee', 'bread']));
```

How do I get `tea` returned. Thank You!

Comment: Try `const nextAction = ([first]) => first ?? "Nothing to do.";`

Answer (score 2):

`=` is assignment operator, so to check if array is empty, you should check for its length instead

```
if (arr.length === 0) { ... }
```

Moreover, to access array element, use `array_variable[index]` instead of just `[0]` or use the function name `nextAction`

```
arr[0]
```

---

#### Demo

```js
function nextAction(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 'Nothing to do.';
  } else {
    return arr[0];
  }
}
console.log(nextAction(['tea', 'coffee', 'bread']));
```

Comment: no prob @JadeYu

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted this:

```js
function nextAction(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 'Nothing to do.';
  } else {
    return arr[0];
  }
}
console.log(nextAction(['tea', 'coffee', 'bread']));
```

Aside from using the assignment operator where a condition is expected, you can't check to see if an array is empty by comparing it to a different array. It's doing identity comparison, and you'd be comparing two different arrays with two different identities.

Also, you were using the function name instead of the parameter.

Then the index needs to be taken from the `arr`. It can't just stand alone. That syntax makes it seem as though you're creating a new array with the number `0` in it.

A more concise way would be like this:

```
function nextAction(arr) {
  return arr.length === 0 ? 'Nothing to do.' : arr[0];
}
console.log(nextAction(['tea', 'coffee', 'bread']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nextAction(arr) {
    if (arr == []) {
        return 'Nothing to do.';
    } else {
        return arr[0];
    }
}
console.log(nextAction(['tea', 'coffee', 'bread']));
```